# Login issue in Mysql through Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I am unable to login to MySQL. I am using Phpmyadmin interface. Please note that it is not #1045 error which has plenty of solutions on the internet including this website. When I try to login it simply shows this error

Cannot log in to the MySQL server

and nothing else no error number or anything else and I'm guessing that my MySQL and PHP server are not starting at all because I also cannot run sites on localhost. I am using WAMP on Windows machine. Please tell me how to solve this problem and I don't want to uninstall and reinstall WAMP because I have not taken backup of all the databases on MySQL and if I uninstall it will delete all the databases. Please help.

Comment: Have you moved the database from a previous install?

Comment: are you able to log in as default user? root with no password?

Comment: @RedZ : No I haven't moved the database and also I'm unable to login as default user with no password.

Comment: I don't have a fix for this problem.
I'm just amazed we both suffered this at the same time.
Have you fixed it yet? None of the other fixes for error codes help, it doesn't show up in the log file as an error, it just plain fails. I logged into my hostgator phpmyadmin account, then from then on, i can't use my WAMP phpmyadmin.

Comment: see my answer please.

Comment: More details please! What did you do? How have you got databases loaded? **Most important** What colour is the wampmanager icon in the system tray?

Comment: @CrazyWorld: No I didn't find any solution and I tried everything including logging into MYSQL through command prompt. Nothing worked so I had to uninstall and reinstall WAMP. I lost all my local databases. So frustrated. Thankfully I had backups of most of them so not much was lost.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your password.  
Left click WAMP in your system tray, go to MySQL > MySQL console.  
Type the following: SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('new_password');  
For no password: SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('');  
more information here 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-user.html